# manage output result (filter + time unit)

Tags: r, filter

Currently I am encountering some difficulties and I would like to receive some advice please.

My aim :
Apply X filters  and display the results by time period (week, month,..)

A final result (very minimal) is below :
I hope this will help other users.

**DATA**

```
Eu1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018,2018, 2018, 2018,2018, 2018, 2018, 2018),
                  month= c("Apr2018", "May2018", "Jan2018", "Mar2018", "June2018", "Oct2018", "Aug2018","Sep2018" , "Dec2018", "Oct2018"),

                  week = c(1,2, 3 , 4, 5 , 6 , 7 , 8,9,10),        
                  
                  unit1= c("District_2", "District_1", "District_1", "District_2", "District_1", "District_2", "District_1", "District_2",
                           "District_2", "District_1"),
                  
                  N= c(70, 63, 48, 55, 35, 41, 39, 30, 25,56) )
```

**code :**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
                 
   #filter              
                 selectInput(inputId = "sel_um", 
                             label = "Unit1",
                             choices = unique(Eu1$unit1), 
                             multiple=TRUE,
                             width = validateCssUnit(250)),
  #scale to display               
                 selectInput("period",        
                             label="Display by ",
                             width = 150,
                             choices = c(
                               "week"="week",
                               "month" = "month",
                               "year"= "Year"),
                             selected = "year" )),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("graph1"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  df_dat <- reactive({
    
 #Filters (insert)
    df_dat  <- Eu1                    
    if (!is.null(input$sel_um)) {
      df_dat  <- df_dat  %>% filter(unit1 == input$sel_um) }
    return(df_dat)
  })
  
#graph 
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({   
    req(df_dat())  # make sure filtered data is not NULL   
  # plot filtered data
    ggplot(df_dat(), aes(x = !!rlang::sym(input$period), y = N)) +
      geom_line()  + geom_point()
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filters for `unit1` to `unit4` actually work as indented. However, the filter for how to display the results (`period`) needs to be set directly in ggplot. As `input$period` is a string, I convert it to a symbol and force the evaluation with `!!`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#DATA
Eu1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  Year = c(2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2018, 2017,
                           2016, 2015, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015,
                           2018, 2017, 2016, 2015),
                  MonthYYYY = c("Apr2018", "May2017", "Jan2016", "Mar2015", "June2018", "Oct2017", "Aug2016","Sep2015" , "Dec2018", "Oct2017",
                                "Apr2018", "May2017", "Jan2016", "Mar2015", "June2018", "Oct2017", "Aug2016","Sep2015" , "Dec2018", "Oct2017",
                                "Apr2018", "May2017", "Jan2016", "Mar2015"),
                  week = c(1,2, 3 , 4, 5 , 6 , 7 , 8,9,10,11,12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24),        
                  
                  unit1= c("District_1", "District_1", "District_1", "District_1",
                           "District_1", "District_1", "District_1", "District_1",
                           "District_1", "District_1", "District_1", "District_1", "District_2",
                           "District_2", "District_2", "District_2", "District_2",
                           "District_2", "District_2", "District_2", "District_2", "District_2",
                           "District_2", "District_2"),
                  
                  unit2= c("UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "Fr", "Fr", "Fr", "Fr", "Ger", "Ger",
                           "Ger", "Ger", "Fr", "Fr", "Fr", "Fr", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK",
                           "Ger", "Ger", "Ger", "Ger"),
                  unit3 = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "FF", "BB", "CC", "DD",  
                            "EE", "AAA", "VV", "FF", "FG", "FF", "BB", "AA", "AA", "AA",
                            "EF", "BC", "GG", "GA"),
                  unit4 = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "FF", "BB", "CC", "DD",  
                            "EE", "AAA", "VV", "FF", "FG", "FF", "BB", "AA", "AA", "AA",
                            "EF", "BC", "GG", "GA"),
                  N= c(70, 63, 48, 55, 35, 41, 39, 30, 2526, 2459, 2326, 2225, 8, 6,
                       7, 14, 23, 25, 28, 29, 734, 713, 696, 698)
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  setBackgroundColor(color = c("#66e0ff", "#00a3cc", "#003d4d")),
  titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(tags$style(".well {background-color:#e6f9ff;}"),
                 
                 
                 selectInput(inputId = "sel_um", 
                             label = "Unit1",
                             choices = unique(Eu1$unit1), 
                             multiple=TRUE,
                             width = validateCssUnit(250)),
                 
                 selectInput(inputId = "sel_uf",
                             label = "Unit2", # UF
                             choices = unique(Eu1$unit2), 
                             multiple=TRUE,
                             width = validateCssUnit(250)),
                 selectInput(inputId = "sel_ghm",
                             label = "unit3",
                             choices = unique(Eu1$unit3), 
                             multiple=TRUE,
                             width = validateCssUnit(250)),
                 
                 selectInput(inputId = "sel_diag", 
                             label = "Unit4",  
                             choices = unique(Eu1$unit3), 
                             multiple=TRUE,
                             width = validateCssUnit(250)),
                 
                 selectInput("period",             #<--------------------- HERE
                             label="Display by ",
                             width = 150,
                             choices = c(
                               "week"="week",
                               "month" = "MonthYYYY",
                               "year"= "Year"),
                             selected = "year" )
                 
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("graph1"))
  )
)





server <- function(input, output){
  
  df_dat <- reactive({
    df_dat <- filter(Eu1, 
                     unit1 %in% input$sel_um, 
                     unit2 %in% input$sel_uf, 
                     unit3 %in% input$sel_ghm, 
                     unit4 %in% input$sel_diag)
    return(df_dat)
  })
  
  # create a graph 
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({
    
    # make sure filtered data is not NULL
    req(df_dat())
    
    # plot filtered data
    ggplot(df_dat(), aes(x = !!rlang::sym(input$period), y = N)) +
      geom_line()  +
      geom_point()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
display time select -> OK.

but the result after filtering don't run.
I thought it could come from the format of the variables but after changing (I worked on selectInput choices and replaced   `choices = unique(Eu1$unit2),` by   `choices = as.character(unique( `), it still doesn't work 
Have you any ideas ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The filtering works for me. But you don't have many entries in your data.frame, that means a lot of combinations of filters are not contained. Try to select several options for every input, then you see points in your plot

Comment: its' curious.
with the same code, when I select only 1 filter (unit1 = district_1), my data frame indicates 0 observations for 8 variables ...

Comment: yes, because the other filters are all `NULL` if nothing is selected, and `NULL` is not a value in your data.frame, so no row is selected